# Unable to click ALT+TAB programmatically ubuntu 21.04

Tags: python, java, 21.04

I'm trying to understand why I am no longer able to perform alt-tab and other manipulations programmatically on Ubuntu 21.04. I guess this functionality won't work at all. Did something change from a security perspective? I'm using `Kernel 5.11.0.40-generic`.

[question from StackOverflow with python and java example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70094240)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed this is due to Ubuntu 21.10 defaulting to the Wayland display driver (also after an upgrade) that uses different protocols and implements security mechanisms. For now, you need to move back to Xorg to keep this working until Python libraries with equivalent functionality become available for Wayland - you will likely need to adapt your code at that point.

To switch from Wayland to Xorg, log out. After selecting your name, click the cog wheel and select the Xorg session before entering your password.

[image]

Comment: For now, you need to move back to X11 - what do you mean under X11?
I guess rollback to the old kernel version is not an option for me (I have AMD Ryzen 7 4800h which works badly with the old kernel version) so I will just wait.

Comment: No, I mean reverting to the X11 instead of Wayland, which can be done from the login screen. I will add some detail

Comment: Works fine! Thank you! On Ubuntu 20.04 use Xorg by default?